# Annoyingly unnatural Sound slider in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, volume-control

First of all I must say that I am suffering here, because of this Sound slider in Ubuntu. It's so unnatural, instead of sliding (because it's called slider) it's jumping 10%, 20%, 30% (maybe even more) when i increase sound using mouse scroll wheel. Is there a way to make it work like in Windows, without hurting my ears.

Comment: @Takkat My mouse scroll speed is fine, but I have the same issue as OP.

Comment: Instead of using the mouse scroll wheel, you can click the speaker icon then click and drag the volume slider.

Comment: @wjandrea: just tested it - the xinput method to change mouse scrolling distance does not work any more indeed. Good catch!

Comment: Yeah i saw in 17.04 it is disaster. any solution to this?

Comment: I switched to 'gnome'... slider is fine with dragging and scrolling here... :)